# Easier Ways to Find General Solutions of Higher Dimensional ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have often used in the 2x2 case the Jordan form of the matrix A (2x2) in the system X' = AX, which yields a nice solution with standard basis vectors, which we transpose by the transformation matrix T to get back the original ODE's general solution (assuming invertible T).

Now with 3x3 and above, calculating the inverse matrix becomes prohibitively tedious, and I wanted to see if there is a faster way when there are repeated eigenvalues.

Example: A = ((0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)), then the eigenvalues are -1, 1, 1, and clearly because x_2' = x_2 (the y component), x_2(t) = c_2 * e^t.  I'm not sure what to do next; I know often we "guess" a solution for the components and check, but I'm stuck here...

Comment: so then, is the solution just the same format as in the case of 3 distinct eigenvalues?  i.e. ae^-t(-1,0,1)+be^t(1,0,1)+ce^t(0,1,0) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just post what Moo explained above.  The solution is similar format as in the case of 3 distinct eigenvalues, because the eigenvectors are linearly independent.

$$ae^{-t}(-1,0,1)+be^t(1,0,1)+ce^t(0,1,0)$$

Comment: Thank you, edited.